# Zend Framework 2 & Doctrine 2 - ManyToMany edit form is empty

Tags: forms, zend-framework2, doctrine

Here is a part of modiffilmAction(), to edit a film title and actors. There is a ManyToMany association between Films and Actors. There's only the title filling the form. If this code can work according to you, can you tell me how to fill the form? Or what's wrong in this code. I haven't found any example.

```
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();

    $qb ->select(array('f','a'))
        ->from('Cine\Entity\Films', 'f')
        ->where($qb->expr()->eq('f.id', '?1'))
        ->innerJoin('f.actors', 'a')
        ->setParameter(1, $id);
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $film = $query->getResult();

    $form = new FilmForm($em);
    $form->bind($film);
    ...
```

If I replace the query, 
$film = $em->find('Cine\Entity\Films', $id); 
using fetch="eager" in the association, it's the same result : no binding data.

I think I haven't understood something very simple but I'm new in zf2 and doctrine 2...
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this;

**Controller Action:**

```
public function editAction()
{
    $film = new Film;

    if ($this->params('id') > 0) {
        $film = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Cine\Entity\Film')->find($this->params('id'));
    }

    $form = new FilmForm($this->getEntityManager());
    $form->setHydrator(new DoctrineEntity($this->getEntityManager(),'Cine\Entity\Film'));
    $form->bind($film);

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setInputFilter($film->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($film);
            $em->flush();

            $this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage('Film Saved');

            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('cine/default', array('controller' => 'film','action' =>  'index'));
        }
    }

    return new ViewModel(array(
        'film' => $film,
        'form' => $form
    ));
}
```

**Form:**

```
<?php
namespace Cine\Form;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Zend\Form\Form;
use Zend\Form\Element;

class FilmForm extends Form
{
public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
{
    parent::__construct('film');

    $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'id',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'hidden',
        ),
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'title',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'options' => array('label' => 'Film Title'),
        'attributes' => array(
            'class' => 'input-xxlarge'
        )
    ));


    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'actors',
        'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Actors',
            'empty_option'    => 'Select Actors',
            'object_manager' => $em,
            'target_class' => 'Cine\Entity\Actor',
            'property' => 'name'
        ),
        'attributes' => array(
            'multiple' => 'multiple',
            'required' => false,
            'class' => 'chosen'
        )
    ));

    $this->add(array(
        'name' => 'submit',
        'attributes' => array(
            'type'  => 'submit',
            'value' => 'Save',
            'id' => 'submitbutton',
        ),
    ));
}
}
```

**View:**

```
<?php

$title = 'Edit Film';
$this->headTitle($title);
?>
<h1><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h1>

<?php   $form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('cine/default', array('controller' => 'film', 'action' => 'edit', 'id' => $film->getId())));
$form->setAttribute('class', 'form-horizontal');

$form->prepare();


echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formHidden($form->get('id'));

//Film Title
echo $this->formRow($form->get('title'));

echo $this->formRow($form->get('actors'));

echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();


?>
```

Comment: sorry but it doesn't work; I add this line $form->setHydrator(... wihout success. Is it because I use a fielset? I verified : $film contains all informations. I wonder if it is possible tu use bind() to fill a complex form such as mine.

Comment: Sorry, I have not had much experience with fieldsets myself. there is a working example of manytoone and manytomany with fieldsets on Github here https://github.com/josielrocha/ZF2---DoctrineModule---ManyToOne- The comments are in Portuguese.